# How can i refresh/reload form when using snapshot in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a form in Angular which uses the following route

```
{
path: 'FarmMaster/:DocId',
component: FarmMasterWrapperComponent,
resolve: {'farmMaster': FarmMasterResolver},
data: { displayName: 'Farm Master' },
},
```

the code in my FarmMasterResolver looks like this

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FarmMasterResolver implements Resolve<IFarmMaster> {

  constructor(
    private farmService: FarmService,
    ) { }

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<IFarmMaster> | Observable<never> {
    return this.farmService.farmMaster(route.paramMap.get('DocId'))
      .pipe(
        catchError(err => {
          return EMPTY;
        }),
      );
  }
}
```

And the code in my FarmMasterWrapperComponent looks like this for the ngOnInit.

```
  ngOnInit() {
      this.farm = this.route.snapshot.data.farmMaster;
      this.state$ = this.route.paramMap.pipe(
          map(() => window.history.state)
      );
  }
```

So my question is can i use any of the existing code to reload the data for my form, as i have a script which will make changes on the back end which wont show until the user reloads the data for the form ?
Not sure if there is a way to call the resolver manually and if so would that reresh this.farm or would i have to rebind it ?

[image]

Comment: Yes, use ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()

Comment: Where and how would i implement this . Also how does that force the system to go to my back end retrieve the data again ?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't read this problem close enough.  I need to read up on router pre-resolve .  1st step to debug is to put a variable before the return in resolve function, subscribe to the value returned, and put in a debugger statement on subscription.  Do you see any data returned?